# Pandas column date transformation

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a date column the data type is datetime64[ns]. there are over 1000 observations in the dataframe. I want to transform the following column:

```
date
2013-05-01
2013-05-01
```

to

```
date
05/2013
05/2013
```

or

```
date
05-2013
05-2013
```

EDIT//

this is my sample code as of now

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':['07/2017','07/2017',pd.NaT]})

           a
0 2017-07-13
1 2017-07-13
2        NaT

test['a'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) == True else x.strftime('%Y-%m'))

0   2017-07-01
1   2017-07-01
2          NaT
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

why did only the date change and not the format?

Comment: Do you want to store the information as a string? If you want to keep it as a proper datetime column, the day information is unavoidable (to my knowledge).

Comment: proper datetime column, if not possible then string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `datetime64` into whatever string format you like using the `strftime` method. In your case you would apply it like this:

```
df.date = df.date[df.date.notnull()].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%Y'))
df.date
Out[111]: 
0    05/2013
1    05/2013
```

Comment: I am getting an error: ValueError: year=1 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900. I do not have any years before 1900.

Comment: can you find out what row it's failing on? (the code works for me on the example you included)

Comment: it's the NaN's. how can i write a lambda function to bypass NaNs?

Comment: got ya, edited my answer with something for you to try